# Succesfully created a virtualenv (using "mkproject") in Dockerfile, but can't run "workon" properly

Tags: docker, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Edit: Solved- typo

I have a Dockerfile that successfully creates a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper (along with setting up a heap of "standard" settings/packages in our normal environment). I am using the resulting image as a "base image" for further use. All good so far.  However, the following Dockerfile (based of the first image, "base_image_14.04") falls down at the last line:

```
FROM base_image_14.04

USER root
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libproj0 libproj-dev \
    libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-dev \
    libjpeg62 libjpeg-dev \
    zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev \
    libgdal20 libgdal-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

USER webdev
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-ic", "mkproject maproxy"]

EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/mapproxy
ADD ./requirements.txt .

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-ic", "workon mapproxy &&  pip install -r requirements.txt"]
```

The "mkproject mapproxy" works fine. If I comment out the last line it builds successfully and I can spin up the container and run "workon mapproxy" manually, not a problem.  But when I try and build with the last line, it gives a workon error:

```
ERROR: Environment 'mapproxy' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv mapproxy'.
```

workon is being called, but for some reason it can't find the mapproxy virtualenv.

WORKON_HOME & PROJECT_HOME both exist (defined in the parent image) and point to the correct locations (and are used successfully by "mkproject mapproxy").

So why is workon returning an error when the mapproxy virtualenv exists?  The same error happens when I isolate that last line into a third Dockerfile building on the second.

Comment: To avoid any issues with virtual environments and non-interactive shells, we just call the executables in the environment explicitly: `$WORKON_HOME/mapproxy/bin/pip`. Maybe that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Solved: It was a simple typo. mkproject maproxy instead of mapproxy. :sigh:

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to build a docker image and am running into similar problems.

First question was why use a virtual env in docker? The main reason in a nutshell is to minimize effort to migrate an existing and working approach into a docker container. I will eventually use docker-compose, but I wanted to start by getting my feet wet with it all in a single docker container.

In my first attempt I installed almost everything with apt-get, including uwsgi. I installed my app "globally" with pip3. The app has command line functionality and a separate flask web app, hence the need for uwsgi. The command line functionality works, but when I make a request of the flask app uwsgi / python has a problem with locale: `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding and ImportError: No module named 'encodings`

I have stripped away all my app specific additions to narrow down the problem. This is the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
# Docker image definition for testing
FROM ubuntu:xenial

# Create a user 
RUN useradd -G sudo -ms /bin/bash tester
RUN echo 'tester:password' | chpasswd
WORKDIR /home/tester   

# Skipping apt-get update to save some build time. Some are kept
# to insure they are the same as on host setup.
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev python3-pip \
    virtualenv virtualenvwrapper sudo nano && \
    apt-get clean -qy

# After above, can we use those installed in rest of Dockerfile?
# Yes, but not always, such as with virtualenvwrapper. What about
# virtualenv? How do you "source" the script? Doesn't appear to be
# installed, as bash complains "source needs a single parameter"
ENV VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON /usr/bin/python3
ENV VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV /usr/bin/virtualenv
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source", "/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh"]

# Create a virtualenv so uwsgi can find locale
# RUN mkdir /home/tester/.virtualenv && virtualenv -p`which python3` /home/bts_tools/.virtualenv/bts_tools
RUN mkvirtualenv -p`which python3` bts_tools && \
    workon bts_tools && \
    pip3 --disable-pip-version-check install --upgrade bts_tools 

USER tester
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["--login"]
```

The build fails on the line I try to source the virtualenvwrapper script. Bash complains source needs an argument - the file to be sourced. So I comment out the RUN lines and it builds without error. When I run the resulting container I see all the additions to the ENV that virtualenvwrapper makes (you can see all of them by executing the "set" command without any args), and the script to be sourced is there too.

So my question is why doesn't docker find them? How does the docker build process work if the results of any previous RUNs or ENVs aren't applied for subsequent use in the Dockerfile? I know some things are applied and work, for example if you `apt-get nginx` you can refer to /etc/nginx or alter things under that folder. You can create a user and set it's password or cd into its home folder for example. If I move the WORKDIR before the `RUN useradd -G` I see a warning from useradd the home folder already exists. I tried to use the "time" program to time how long it takes to do various things in the Dockerfile and docker complains it can't find 'time'.

So what exactly is going on? I have spent the last 3 days trying to figure this out. It just shouldn't be this difficult. What am I missing?

Parts of the bts_tools flask app worked when I wasn't using virtual envs. Most of the app didn't work, and the issue was this locale problem. Since everything works on the host outside of docker, and after trying to alter the PATH, PYTHONHOME, PYTHONPATH in my uwsgi start script to overcome the dreaded "locale encoding" fatal error, I decided to try to replicate the host setup as closely as possible since that didn't have the locale issue. When I have had that problem before I could run `dpkg-reconfigure python3` or fix with changes to PATH or ENV settings. If you google the problem you'll see many people have difficulties with python & locale. It's almost enough reason to avoid using python!

I posted [this](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1688#issuecomment-383315753) elsewhere about locale issue, if it helps.